# Asp.Net MVC Redirect anonymous users to a banner page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am still a little new with Asp.Net Mvc and I am trying to figure out how to force anonymous users to my banner page. Here is my issue, I have several pages that I have [AllowAnonymous] on because the user is still registering or logging in, but I need to force the user to initially hit the banner page and agree to terms before proceeding. I am not sure how to keep the user from being able to go directly to the login page via the url and bypassing the banner page. I appreciate any help someone can give me.

Comment: You could do this using a common js file in all your anonymous pages that can read/set a cookie to determine if the banner page has been displayed or not.  Alternatively you can use session variables in your controller(s) to read/set a flag that indicates if the banner page has been displayed for a given session and redirect at the controller level.

Answer (score 1):

One solution:

1. Set a session variable once the user agrees to the terms on the Banner page.
2. Create a custom [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) that checks for the existence of the variable and redirects to your banner page if it's not set.

   ```
   var agreed = Session["Agreed"];
   if (agreed == null || agreed.ToString() != "1") {
       Redirect("/Banner");
   }
   ```
3. Decorate your Login `HttpGet` action with the custom attribute.

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   [MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute]
   public ActionResult Login()
   ```